# inheriting a JFrame from another class using actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jframe

I am trying to use inheritence to pull a JFrame from another class once a button is pushed on the first JFrame. I am unsure of how to do this properly and keep getting different errors. This is the current code I have. Can someone help me out/walk me through the proper way to do this using the code I have? or do I need to rewrite everything?

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

public class acmeBankLogin {


    private JFrame frmAcmeBankLogin;
    private JPasswordField passwordInput;
    private JTextField usernameInput;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    acmeBankLogin window = new acmeBankLogin();
                    window.frmAcmeBankLogin.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public acmeBankLogin() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmAcmeBankLogin = new JFrame();
        frmAcmeBankLogin.setTitle("ACME Bank Login");
        frmAcmeBankLogin.setBounds(100, 100, 435, 230);
        frmAcmeBankLogin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password:");

        passwordInput = new JPasswordField(4);
        usernameInput = new JTextField();
        usernameInput.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String password = passwordInput.getText();
                String username = usernameInput.getText();

                if (username.trim().toLowerCase().equals("uccs") && password.trim().equals("1234")) {

                    acmeBank acmeBank = new acmeBank();
                    frmAcmeBank = new JFrame();

                }

                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username/password!");

                }

            }

        });

        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frmAcmeBankLogin.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(groupLayout
                .createSequentialGroup().addGap(43)
                .addGroup(groupLayout
                        .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(lblNewLabel).addComponent(lblNewLabel_1))
                .addGap(34)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false).addComponent(passwordInput)
                        .addComponent(usernameInput, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 131, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(156, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING,
                        groupLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(287, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(51)));
        groupLayout
                .setVerticalGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(47)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                                        .addComponent(usernameInput, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(9).addComponent(btnNewButton).addGap(14)
                                .addGroup(
                                        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(lblNewLabel_1)
                                                .addComponent(passwordInput, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        frmAcmeBankLogin.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }

}
```

the inheretence should be taking place on line 74. after the correct username and password are put in.

Comment: Which is line 74? What errors are you getting? I'm not sure you're using the word "inheritance" correctly... can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character. Learn by example. All classes in the JDK follow this convention. *after the correct username and password are put in.* - you want to: 1) dispose of the login frame and then 2) create a new JFrame and add components to it and then make that frame visible.

Comment: i'm just going off what I am learning in school. This is how we are taught to do it in my class. the assignment requires us to keep both JFrames in seperate classes and call the second one once the correct login info is put in.

Comment: *the assignment requires us to keep both JFrames in seperate classes* - as it should which it what I suggested in my answer. The code for each frame must be in a separate class, but you need to create an instance of the second frame in the first class.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop using form editors, they aren't helping.  Make the time and effort to learn how to use layout managers and discover the best practices for the framework.
2. The main issue isn't about inheritance, it's about declaring variables.  `frmAcmeBank` isn't declared anywhere, which is your error.

Start by updating the code to something more like...

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String password = passwordInput.getText();
        String username = usernameInput.getText();

        if (username.trim().toLowerCase().equals("uccs") && password.trim().equals("1234")) {

            acmeBank acmeBank = new acmeBank();
            JFrame frmAcmeBank = new JFrame();

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username/password!");

        }

    }
});
```

Now look towards the top of the `initialize` method to see how you would go about adding `acmeBank` to a `JFrame` ... assuming that `acmeBank` is a component.

A better, overall, solution would be to make use of a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

You may also want to take a look at [Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).  It will make it easier for you to read other peoples code and for other people to read yours

## A "better" approach

The following examples demonstrates the use [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as well as introducing concepts such as [delegation](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html), [dependency Injection](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/dependency_injection.html) and the [observer](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/observer.html) patterns.  These are common patterns used in programming and provide you with a set of common tools and leads to a more flexible and maintainable design.

The example also demonstrates the principle of "coding to interface", for [reference](https://medium.com/javarevisited/oop-good-practices-coding-to-the-interface-baea84fd60d3) and [reference](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2076468/smarter-java-development.html)

Why is this important?  Consider this.  You have a "authentication" workflow.  Right now, you workflow is tightly coupled to your `acmeBankLogin` class.  What happens if you want to change that work to use a file?  What if you want to change the structure of that file from plain text to XML or JSON or have the file compressed or encrypted or you want to use a database or web service? All of that will require you to modify the `acmeBankLogin` which could lead to no end of bugs and issues.

A better solution is to decouple the responsibility for the authentication from the `acmeBankLogin` class and "delegate" its responsibility else where and "inject" it into the class.

So, we start with a basic "contract"

```
public interface Account {
    public String getName();
}

public interface Authenticator {
    public Account autenticate(String userName, char[] password);
}
```

This just says that any implementations of `Authenticator` will provide a single method to perform the authentication workflow and pass back an instance of `Account` (or `null` if they are unauthenticated), we don't care about the underlying implementation details, only that when we call any of the contract methods, it will do it's job.

Next, we design our login view to accept an instance of `Authenticator` and use it to perform the actual authentication.

In this case, the `LoginPane` simply becomes responsible for getting the input from the user and passing it to the authenticator, simple.

```
public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

    public static interface LoginListener {
        public void loginDidSucceeded(LoginPane source, Account account);
    }

    private JTextField userNameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    private LoginListener loginListener;

    public LoginPane(Authenticator authenticator, LoginListener loginListener) {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        this.loginListener = loginListener;

        userNameField = new JTextField(10);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 12, 0);

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Bank of Smaug");
        title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));

        add(title, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        add(new JLabel("User name:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        add(userNameField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(passwordField, gbc);

        JPanel actionPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(actionPane, gbc);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        actionPane.add(loginButton);

        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Account account = authenticator.autenticate(userNameField.getText(), passwordField.getPassword());
                if (account != null) {
                    loginListener.loginDidSucceeded(LoginPane.this, account);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPane.this, "Authentication failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You will also note that the `LoginPane` accepts an instance of `LoginListener`, which acts an "observer" for interested parties to be told when, in this case, authentication was successful.  This decouples the `LoginPane` from the responsibility of knowing what should be done next, as that's not its responsibility.

That's a nice start, but we really need some way to manage the users navigation.  For this I started with a `BankPanel`.  This is responsible for deciding the "top level" navigation flow (from login to account details)...

```
public class BankPane extends JPanel {

    protected enum View {
        LOGIN, ACCOUNT;
    }

    private Authenticator authenticator;
    private LoginPane loginPane;
    private AccountPane accountPane;

    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    public BankPane(Authenticator authenticator) {
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        setLayout(cardLayout);

        this.authenticator = authenticator;

        add(getLoginPane(), View.LOGIN.name());
        add(getAccountPane(), View.ACCOUNT.name());

        present(View.LOGIN);
    }

    protected void present(View view) {
        cardLayout.show(this, view.name());
    }

    public Authenticator getAuthenticator() {
        return authenticator;
    }

    protected LoginPane getLoginPane() {
        if (loginPane != null) {
            return loginPane;
        }

        loginPane = new LoginPane(getAuthenticator(), new LoginPane.LoginListener() {
            @Override
            public void loginDidSucceeded(LoginPane source, Account account) {
                getAccountPane().setAccount(account);
                present(View.ACCOUNT);
            }
        });

        return loginPane;
    }

    protected AccountPane getAccountPane() {
        if (accountPane != null) {
            return accountPane;
        }

        accountPane = new AccountPane(new AccountPane.AccountListener() {
            @Override
            public void didLogoutFromAccount(AccountPane source) {
                present(View.LOGIN);
            }
        });
        return accountPane;
    }

}
```

It should be noted that it would be entirely possible for the `AccountPane` to act as "navigation controller" in of itself, presenting different views associated with the account, so don't think you have to have a single "god" class to perform these operations, but take the time to design the concepts

## Runnable example

All of that presents just part of the picture, below is a runnable example of the concepts I've presented above...

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Authenticator authenticator = new DefaultAuthenticator();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new BankPane(authenticator));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Account {
        public String getName();
    }

    public interface Authenticator {
        public Account autenticate(String userName, char[] password);
    }

    public class DefaultAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

        @Override
        public Account autenticate(String userName, char[] password) {
            if ("Bilbo".equals(userName) && Arrays.equals(password, new char[]{'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'})) {
                return new DefaultAccount("Bilbo Baggins");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class DefaultAccount implements Account {

        private String name;

        public DefaultAccount(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    public class BankPane extends JPanel {

        protected enum View {
            LOGIN, ACCOUNT;
        }

        private Authenticator authenticator;
        private LoginPane loginPane;
        private AccountPane accountPane;

        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        public BankPane(Authenticator authenticator) {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(cardLayout);

            this.authenticator = authenticator;

            add(getLoginPane(), View.LOGIN.name());
            add(getAccountPane(), View.ACCOUNT.name());

            present(View.LOGIN);
        }

        protected void present(View view) {
            cardLayout.show(this, view.name());
        }

        public Authenticator getAuthenticator() {
            return authenticator;
        }

        protected LoginPane getLoginPane() {
            if (loginPane != null) {
                return loginPane;
            }

            loginPane = new LoginPane(getAuthenticator(), new LoginPane.LoginListener() {
                @Override
                public void loginDidSucceeded(LoginPane source, Account account) {
                    getAccountPane().setAccount(account);
                    present(View.ACCOUNT);
                }
            });

            return loginPane;
        }

        protected AccountPane getAccountPane() {
            if (accountPane != null) {
                return accountPane;
            }

            accountPane = new AccountPane(new AccountPane.AccountListener() {
                @Override
                public void didLogoutFromAccount(AccountPane source) {
                    present(View.LOGIN);
                }
            });
            return accountPane;
        }

    }

    public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

        public static interface LoginListener {

            public void loginDidSucceeded(LoginPane source, Account account);
        }

        private JTextField userNameField;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;

        private LoginListener loginListener;

        public LoginPane(Authenticator authenticator, LoginListener loginListener) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            this.loginListener = loginListener;

            userNameField = new JTextField(10);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 12, 0);

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Bank of Smaug");
            title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));

            add(title, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            add(new JLabel("User name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            add(userNameField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(passwordField, gbc);

            JPanel actionPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(actionPane, gbc);

            JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
            actionPane.add(loginButton);

            loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Account account = authenticator.autenticate(userNameField.getText(), passwordField.getPassword());
                    if (account != null) {
                        loginListener.loginDidSucceeded(LoginPane.this, account);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginPane.this, "Authentication failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class AccountPane extends JPanel {

        public interface AccountListener {

            public void didLogoutFromAccount(AccountPane source);
        }

        private Account account;
        private AccountListener accountListener;

        private JLabel accountNameLabel;

        public AccountPane(AccountListener accountListener) {
            this.accountListener = accountListener;

            accountNameLabel = new JLabel();
            accountNameLabel.setFont(accountNameLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Bank of Smaug");
            title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 12, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(title, gbc);

            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;

            add(new JLabel("Account of "), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            add(accountNameLabel, gbc);

            gbc.insets = new Insets(16, 16, 16, 16);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            JLabel summaryLabel = new JLabel("All your gold is belong to us");
            summaryLabel.setFont(summaryLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));
            add(summaryLabel, gbc);
        }

        public void setAccount(Account account) {
            this.account = account;
            accountNameLabel.setText(account.getName());
        }

        public Account getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

    }
}
```

And also take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

> This is for a school assignment and I have to do it a certain way in order to get credit. He only taught us how to use the editors and expects us to use them. For instance one requirement for the code is to use the passwordText box which is in the editor. There's nothing I can do about that.

Okay, this doesn't change anything (other than my continued dislike of your instructor).

The concepts of dependency injection, code hiding, decouple, etc all still hold.  The below example is (as much as you have provided) modified with the above the recommendations

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Authenticator authenticator = new DefaultAuthenticator();
                AcmeBankLogin login = new AcmeBankLogin(authenticator, new AcmeBankLogin.LoginListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void loginDidSucceeded(AcmeBankLogin source, Account account) {
                        source.frmAcmeBankLogin.dispose();
                        AcmeBank bank = new AcmeBank(account, new AcmeBank.BankListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void didLogoutOfAccount(AcmeBank source) {
                            }
                        });
                        bank.frmAcmeBank.pack();
                        bank.frmAcmeBank.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        bank.frmAcmeBank.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
                login.frmAcmeBankLogin.pack();
                login.frmAcmeBankLogin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                login.frmAcmeBankLogin.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Account {

        public String getName();
    }

    public interface Authenticator {

        public Account autenticate(String userName, char[] password);
    }

    public class DefaultAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

        @Override
        public Account autenticate(String userName, char[] password) {
            if ("Bilbo".equals(userName) && Arrays.equals(password, new char[]{'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'})) {
                return new DefaultAccount("Bilbo Baggins");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class DefaultAccount implements Account {

        private String name;

        public DefaultAccount(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }

    public class AcmeBankLogin {

        public static interface LoginListener {

            public void loginDidSucceeded(AcmeBankLogin source, Account account);
        }

        private JFrame frmAcmeBankLogin;
        private JPasswordField passwordInput;
        private JTextField usernameInput;

        private Authenticator authenticator;
        private LoginListener loginListener;

        /**
         * Create the application.
         */
        public AcmeBankLogin(Authenticator authenticator, LoginListener loginListener) {
            this.authenticator = authenticator;
            this.loginListener = loginListener;
            initialize();
        }

        public Authenticator getAuthenticator() {
            return authenticator;
        }

        public LoginListener getLoginListener() {
            return loginListener;
        }

        /**
         * Initialize the contents of the frame.
         */
        private void initialize() {
            frmAcmeBankLogin = new JFrame();
            frmAcmeBankLogin.setTitle("ACME Bank Login");
            frmAcmeBankLogin.setBounds(100, 100, 435, 230);
            //frmAcmeBankLogin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");

            JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password:");

            passwordInput = new JPasswordField(4);
            usernameInput = new JTextField();
            usernameInput.setColumns(10);

            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Submit");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Account account = getAuthenticator().autenticate(usernameInput.getText(), passwordInput.getPassword());
                    if (account != null) {
                        getLoginListener().loginDidSucceeded(AcmeBankLogin.this, account);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAcmeBankLogin, "You are not authorised", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }

                    //String password = passwordInput.getText();
                    //String username = usernameInput.getText();
                    //
                    //if (username.trim().toLowerCase().equals("uccs") && password.trim().equals("1234")) {
                    //
                    //    acmeBank acmeBank = new acmeBank();
                    //    frmAcmeBank = new JFrame();
                    //
                    //} else {
                    //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username/password!");
                    //
                    //}
                }

            });

            GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frmAcmeBankLogin.getContentPane());
            groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(groupLayout
                    .createSequentialGroup().addGap(43)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout
                            .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(lblNewLabel).addComponent(lblNewLabel_1))
                    .addGap(34)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false).addComponent(passwordInput)
                            .addComponent(usernameInput, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 131, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap(156, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING,
                            groupLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(287, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(51)));
            groupLayout
                    .setVerticalGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(47)
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                                            .addComponent(usernameInput, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                    GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGap(9).addComponent(btnNewButton).addGap(14)
                                    .addGroup(
                                            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(lblNewLabel_1)
                                                    .addComponent(passwordInput, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                            GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
            frmAcmeBankLogin.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
        }

    }

    public class AcmeBank {

        public static interface BankListener {

            public void didLogoutOfAccount(AcmeBank source);
        }

        private JFrame frmAcmeBank;

        private Account account;
        private BankListener bankListener;

        /**
         * Create the application.
         */
        public AcmeBank(Account account, BankListener bankListener) {
            this.account = account;
            this.bankListener = bankListener;
            initialize();
        }

        public Account getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

        public BankListener getBankListener() {
            return bankListener;
        }

        /**
         * Initialize the contents of the frame.
         */
        private void initialize() {
            frmAcmeBank = new JFrame();
            frmAcmeBank.setTitle("ACME Bank Login");
            frmAcmeBank.setBounds(100, 100, 435, 230);
            JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
            frmAcmeBank.setContentPane(content);

            frmAcmeBank.add(new JLabel("All your money is belong to us"));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Although I do appreciate the input and the material is definalely useful I am unable to use it. This is for a school assignment and I have to do it a certain way in order to get credit. He only taught us how to use the editors and expects us to use them. For instance one requirement for the code is to use the passwordText box which is in the editor. There's nothing I can do about that.

Comment: So, you missed my use of`JPasswordTextField` - which is standard Swing component?  The problem you're going to have, is passing information between your classes and as you're discovering, form editors lock you in and make it difficult to adjust the UI

Comment: You should also beware, things like, dependency injection and observers are standard development practices, and the use of form editors "shouldn't" interfere with this concept.  You can even use `CardLayout` with form editors, if you know how.  The problem is, form editors make you lazy and tend to lock you into a given workflow (like using frames over panels)

Comment: What I need you to do is learn how the example works and then apply it back to your problem/workflow - you are seldom going to find the "exact", "perfect", "copy'n'paste" solution to you problems, instead, you're going to have to learn to adapt solutions which are "close" to solve "parts" of your problems

Comment: my apologies if I came off ignorant towards you, it wasn't my intention. I did see it but I assume he will know the difference and I am not sure if he wants us to hand write the code. Not to mention we were not taught it so I don't even understand a large portion of your code. Although I do get the general concept of a majority of it I don't actually know what it is or what it does. I am definately going to come back to it and mess with what you gave me. I did end up finding a solution (took me several days) by inputing ```SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ACME());```

Comment: If you "must" use the form editor, then do so, but the basic principle of what I've presented doesn't change and you can still make use if it to solve you're underlying problems (and no, you didn't come of ignorant or arrogant ;))